# How to link storage path of domain to sub domain in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-storage

I have two laravel project on shared hosting one admin panel and another website . main site is on **/public_html directory** and another on **/portal directory** .

```
-----(/home/onomy)
     +portal
       |-subdomain laravel project
     +public_html
       |- domain laravel project
```

All the file need to fetched and upload in /public_html laravel project directory where main site is hosted.

like main site :example.com located at public_html like admin site at admin.example.com when i upload file from admin.example.com file should stored in example.com storage_path and also fetched from example.com storage_path.

**Where should i change to map domain storage to subdomain storage**

how can i do that, is any change on **config/filesystem.php** or **config/path.php**

I am new in laravel, please help.

Answer (score 0):

In your subdomain project you could create a new "disk" in `config/filesystem.php`:

```
'public_html' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => '/home/onomy/public_html/storage',
    'url' => env('PUBLIC_URL').'/storage', // should point to your main project
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

You should do then all file operations through this disk. Hope I got your question right and this helps.

Comment: When i using above code, showing me **relative path** as **storage/..../filename**. I have changed it in PUBLIC_URL but not Showing **absolute path**. Could you please check